# Spot check my translation for engagement ring

Tags: english-to-latin-translation

I know 0 latin, but I am trying to translate a short phrase to get engraved on an engagement ring.
Obviously Google translate and other online services are gonna be problematic, so I searched through common phrases and tried to piece a sentence together.

Hoping someone can spot check my work/recommend any improvements/fixes.

My Phrase: Two made one under god

Translated phrase: duo iuncta in unum sub Deo

Thanks

Comment: For one, it should be *duo **iuncti***. Also you might perhaps prefer *coniungere* over *iungere* as it is more frequently used for marriage (cf. *coniunx* = spouse). More stylistically, why the past tense on an engagement ring? And *sub Deo* is correct grammatically, but to the best of my knowledge a completely unusual expression in Christianity. Something more traditional like *Deo benedicente* might be preferrable.

Comment: Are you going for a Christian angle? You seem to be riffing off of Mark 10:8-9 ("et erunt duo in carne una. Itaque jam non sunt duo, sed una caro. Quod ergo Deus conjunxit, homo non separet.") Might be a good idea to incorporate that. I also second Sebastian's worry about the wording: In the (old) Catholic ceremony for betrothals, the future tense is used for all the vows, so it's a bit strange to treat an engagement ring as a wedding band.

Comment: @SebastianKoppehel "two things have been joined into one under God". I think this could work. It is not so rude in Latin to refer to people as things as it is in English. But I agree that *juncti* is more what I would expect. I also think that the past tense could work if you think of the ring as a reminder, but maybe the past tense is more appropriate for a wedding ring than for an engagement ring.